# recoding integers sequences

Tags: r, dplyr

Beginning with a data.frame object containing one column :

```
 id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 , 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5)

 id <-  as.data.frame(id)
```

My output : each sequence of integers begin with 1 and contains 2 and more single/duplicates integers :

```
id
1   # First sequence on integers            
1               
1               
2               
3               
3               
1  # second  sequence on integers               
1               
2               
2
2               
3               
1   # third sequence on integers                
2               
3               
3               
3               
1   # fourth sequence on integers               
2               
3
4               
5               
5               
5
```

Expected result:
I want to recode my values.

```
id2
1           
1               
1               
2               
3               
3               
4   
4               
5               
5
5               
6               
7           
8               
9               
9               
9               
10          
11              
12
13          
14              
14              
14
```

I am trying tu use `group_by` / `ungroup`  verbs from `dplyr` r package.

Here is the the approach considered :

```
library(dplyr)

id2 <- id %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate id2 =   %>%   # needing some help !
 ungroup %>%
 select(2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rleid`

```
data.frame(id2 = data.table::rleid(id$id))
```

---

Or with `rle` from `base R`

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(id$id), values <- seq_along(values)))
```

Comment: Great. How to keep id column? (id, id2)

Comment: @Wilcar  You can use `data.frame(id = id$id, id2 = data.table:L:rleid(id$id))`